# How to remove file template in Emacs

Tags: emacs

Every time I create an HTML file in Emacs a template is being loaded. It asks me for title and creates the following text:

```
<html>
    <head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1></h1>

<address>
<a href="mailto:my_email"></a>
</address>
</body>
</html>
```

But I don't need it. How to disable this template? I am using yasnippet, maybe, it creates it?

Comment: `yasnippet` doesn't do this (I use it too, and it doesn't apply templates to any default mode I open). It looks like you've enabled an email template somewhere, but I'm not entirely sure how you'd go about turning that off. Could you perhaps pastebin your `.emacs` file?

Comment: "Could you perhaps pastebin your .emacs file?" I could, but it's too large. I'll try to find the template myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. The cause were these lines in .emacs:

```
(auto-insert-mode)
(setq auto-insert-query nil)
```

Seems, that this module inserts the template when you are creating a file.